# 'IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported' error occurring only occasionally

Tags: java

I'm playing audio using `SourceDataLine` in Java and occasionally I'll get an error stating:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

However most of the time I don't get this error, and everything works fine. I can't a reason for this online or in my code. The line that throws this is:

```
line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(targetFormat, null);
```

The only pointer I can find is that, on the JavaDoc it mentions that this exception is thrown

> if a matching source data line is not available from the specified mixer due to resource restrictions

Could it be that after the previous song ended, the line wasn't released by `line.close()`?

Comment: According to doc, `null` parameter for the API picks up the systems default mixer. The exception you see seems to be because the system default mixer doesn't like the `targetFormat`

Comment: @svasa Yes, I know this is the standard reason, but I'm repeatedly using the same file, the same target format etc. but this only happens occasionally, like 1 in 10 times

Comment: You could probably add some check like : `DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, targetFormat);
 if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) { line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(targetFormat, null ); }`

Comment: @svasa Good call on the checks, however it somewhat scuppers my program if it can't play when it should be able to. Nonetheless, I'll add that and see if it can recover from it or if, once it fails once, that's it.

Comment: You can add an `else` to that if  and debug to enter the `else` to see what is the real issue ?